# Orion subscriptions do not detect the removal of entities

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Subscriptions detect the creation and update of entities but do not detect the removal of entities.

- Subscription creation:

POST http://myhost:orion_port/v2/subscriptions

```
{
    "description": "Send a notification to detect any change",
    "subject": {
        "entities": [{
            "idPattern": ".*"
        }]
    },
    "notification": {
        "http": {
            "url": "http://myhost:myport/myendpoint"
        }
    }
}
```

- Entity creation:

POST http://myhost:iot_aget_json_port/iot/devices

```
{
    "devices": [{
        "device_id": "entity_test_agent",
        "entity_name": "entity_test_orion",
        "entity_type": "test",
        "transport": "HTTP",
        "protocol": "IoTA-JSON",
        "attributes": [{
             "object_id": "status",
             "name": "status",
             "type": "Text"
        }],
        "static_attributes": [{
             "name": "name",
             "type": "Text",
             "value": "Test"
        }]
    }]
```

}

- Entity update:

PUT http://myhost:orion_port/v2/entities/entity_test_orion/attrs/name

```
{
     "value": true
}
```

- Delete entity:

DELETE http://myhost:orion_port/v2/entities/entity_test_orion

DELETE http://myhost:iot_aget_json_port/iot/devices/entity_test_agent

First, I send the subscription creation to detect changes in entities.

Later, I create an entity and the subscription is executed without problems. Then I update the entity name and I receive the subscription again perfectly, but if I delete the entity I do not receive any event.

There are any way to receive subscription events to detect when an entity is deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are not subscriptions that deal with delete events

Comment: The following item in the Orion roadmap is about implementing this functionality: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1494. Eventually it will be addressed. If you find it interesting you can show your support adding a +1  to it :)